# AutoMapper - Using ProjectTo method

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-7.0

I am using AutoMapper in my code and I wanna use `ProjectTo` for the mappings like this:

```cs
var queryable = await _unitOfWork.ProductRepository
              .GetList(query);
return new Paging<ProductListDto>
{
    Data = queryable.Data.ProjectTo<ProductListDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList()
};
```

but I got the following error while using `ProjectTo`:

[image]

Comment: [`.ProjectTo()`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) is an extension methods for `IQueryable` provided by AutoMapper. `IEnumerable` doesn't contain `.ProjectTo()` method. You should use a basic `_mapper.Map()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProjectTo` method only supports [`IQueryable`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) but not `IEnumerable`.

You should use the basic [`_mapper.Map<T>(/* source */)`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper).

```cs
return new Paging<ProductListDto>
{
    Data = _mapper.Map<List<ProductListDto>>(queryable.Data)
};
```